# in re log in page, java.sql.SQLException: database is locked

Tags: java, sqlite

In this log in frame when log in first it works well after log out if i want to log in again I get a massage "java.sql.SQLException: database is locked" . How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Connection after each query. If any of the connections still persist, You would see the same error.

Reading from SQLite database sets the locking state to Shared. Multiple readers can actively read from the database at the same time.

While writing to an SQLite database sets the locking state to Exclusive state. That means that no other processes can be active at that time and your database if locked.
See the details about the locking schemes [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)